# Issue with Eclipse Running Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

Many times when I run android application using Eclipse. Eclipse stuck on building the project and then I have to restart to fix this. What could be the actual solution for this problem. It wastes a lot of time.
It stucks of Lauching Delegate 27 %

Comment: whats your problem bar is showing @ that time?

Comment: nothing. But Progress Bar is showing Launching Delegate 27%.

Comment: I mean that problem tab like console, logcat...

Comment: nothing because launching is stuck.

Comment: In Eclipse Go to project-> Build Automatically check once and runit.

Comment: A possible cause of this is not having run or debug configurations present. Goto Run/Debug configurations and create a new one to run/debug your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, were you able to run android applications before? Are you using an emulator or connecting to an actual device?

Comment: same machine and same device. But it is creating problem now. I updated Eclipse and problems has been started is there any way to downgrade it?

Comment: Found this over at project pages as Issue #21073, answered by benpar:

Update: This scenario can also be avoided if the AVD emulator is launched from the AVD Manager within Eclipse. The issue happens when launching the first emulator from the Run button in Eclipse.

To avoid:

1.Start Eclipse
2.Window -> AVD Manager
3.Start an emulator
4.Run the project

Comment: but m not working with emulator. I have an android Device. Does the above scenario applies on Devices?

Answer (score 1):

your system speed is slow (I think process is slower then 2.0GHZ and ram is less then 2gb).Upgrade them .

Comment: I dont think my system is slow. 2.3 Dual Core 2 GB DDR3 Is it slow? for eclipse?